Using 3DP.Rocks software for modeling a lithophane using the dome-on top option
I made the model with the 3DP.Rocks software. I sliced the design with Prusa Slicer 2.8.1. The finished product was indeed a lithophane. The problem however was that the base of the dome was so thick that a light behind the dome failed to illuminate the lithophane.
I have made curved and straight panel lithophanes that worked perfectly. When I saw the dome option, I thought I would give it a try. No luck, any ideas?

Hi and welcome Tony! You'll need to include some photos. The 3D model would also be useful.

Could you add photos of the print and possibly cut out views of the STL or sliced file?
